# How can I convert an Array of elements into a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom

First thing's first: **this isn't asking to how to turn a NodeList into an Array**. This is the opposite.

For consistency's sake, I would like to create a function that returns a NodeList, just like `document.querySelectorAll()` does.

Here's my current code:

```
var toNodeList = function(arrayOfNodes){
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  arrayOfNodes.forEach(function(item){
    fragment.appendChild(item);
  });
  return fragment.childNodes;
};
```

However this removes the original elements from the DOM!

How can I make a `NodeList` in a non-destructive fashion?

Comment: Hi @DominicTobias, I mean the nodes inside arrayOfNodes (generated previously) are being removed from the DOM.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a nodeList, but here you go -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dzu2m/**

Comment: @adeneo Hrm, adding a temporary class to each element, running querySelectorAll() and then removing the class. It works, but it's obviously a little hacky.

Comment: You can't really create a nodeList, only native methods can, so the only way to get a nodeList with DOM elements is to select them, and adding something unique to the elements is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: @adeneo do you have a citation for that? If so add it as an answer.

Comment: @adeneo `console.log( isNodeList( toNodeList(arr) ) )` is giving false!! Also, if I add another div with a class of `custom_class` but not in the array, I get that element too, so ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to clone the node.

```
var toNodeList = function(arrayOfNodes){
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  arrayOfNodes.forEach(function(item){
    fragment.appendChild(item.cloneNode());
  });
  return fragment.childNodes;
};
```

Note pass `true` to `cloneNode` to make a deep clone.

Comment: Just just discovered `cloneNode()` at the same time you answered that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this returns clones, so you're no longer working with the elements in the DOM

Comment: Ah @adeneo you're right. Since the purpose of this is to have a reference to the original elements to manipulate later, `.cloneNode` won't work. Going to leave this open to see if there's a way I can have a NodeList that has a reference to the original nodes (eg, like what `document.querySelectorAll()` returns).

Comment: @mikemaccana I was wondering if you wanted that but then what is the purpose of not using `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @dominic I don't wish to return a NodeList with every node in the DOM that matches a selector, just return a NodeList (based on other criteria).

Comment: @mikemaccana NodeList's are readonly but check this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075234/is-it-possible-to-append-an-element-to-a-javascript-nodelist

Comment: lol @Dominic I forgot to accept this answer 8 years ago.