# How to concatenate two NodeList objects into one, avoiding duplicates

Tags: javascript

I am writing a few functions to simplify my interaction with Javascript Nodes, here is the source-code so far:

```
Node.prototype.getClasses = function() {
    return this.className ? this.className.split(" ") : "";
};

Node.prototype.hasClass = function(c) {
    return this.getClasses().indexOf(c) >= 0;
};

Node.prototype.addClass = function(c) {
    if (!this.hasClass(c)) {
        this.className += " " + c;
    }
    return this;
};

Node.prototype.removeClass = function(c) {
    if (this.hasClass(c)) {
        var classes = this.getClasses();
        var newClasses = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < classes.length; index++) {
            if (classes[index] !== c) {
                newClasses.push(classes[index]);
            }
        }
        this.className = newClasses.join(" ");
    }
    return this;
};

function NodeCollection(nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
    this.addClass = (c) => {
        for (var nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < this.nodes.length; nodeIndex++) {
            this.nodes[nodeIndex].addClass(c);
        }
        return this.nodes;
    };
    this.removeClass = (c) => {
        for (var nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < this.nodes.length; nodeIndex++) {
            this.nodes[nodeIndex].removeClass(c);
        }
        return this.nodes;
    };
    this.getHTML = () => {
        var output = "";
        for (var nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < this.nodes.length; nodeIndex++) {
            output += this.nodes[nodeIndex].outerHTML;
        }
        return output;
    };
    this.each = (f) => {
        for (var nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < this.nodes.length; nodeIndex++) {
            f(this.nodes[nodeIndex]);
        }
        return this.nodes;
    };
}

Node.prototype.query = function(s) {
    return new NodeCollection(this.querySelectorAll(s));
};

Node.prototype.siblings = function(s) {
    var rawSiblings = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(s);
    var output = [];
    for (var siblingIndex = 0; siblingIndex < rawSiblings.length; siblingIndex++) {
        if ((rawSiblings[siblingIndex].parentNode === this.parentNode) && (rawSiblings[siblingIndex] !== this)) {
            output.push(rawSiblings[siblingIndex]);
        }
    }
    return new NodeCollection(output);
};
```

Everything is working great and I am quite content with these functions, I have managed to prevent a lot of headaches without the usage of Javascript frameworks (a hobby project).

Now, I would like to be able to write a query function for `NodeCollection` as well, however, I am not quite aware of how should I concatenate the `nodes` members of the `NodeCollection` objects, which are instances of `NodeList`. I would like to write something like this as a member function of `NodeCollection`:

```
this.query = (s) => {
    //create an empty NodeList
    for (var index = 0; index < this.nodes.length; index++) {
        //concat this[nodes][index] to the node list created outside the 
        //cycle avoiding possible duplicates
    }
    //return the concatenated NodeList
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to query the existing nodes inside the NodeCollection or add the results of query to DOM to the existing nodes?

Comment: Why not turn the nodeList to a proper array, and then you can freely concat.
this.nodes = Array.from(nodes);

Comment: Using jQuery, you solve it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I would like to query the existing nodes inside the NodeCollection and return a concatenated result without duplicates.

Comment: @LajosArpad concatenate the result with which array? the same nodelist which you have just queried?

Comment: @OrrSiloni the reason is that querySelectorAll returns a NodeList and I would like to be consistent with that. Of course your suggestion is an alternative, which, if there is no solution to concatenate NodeList objects might turn out to be the road to go on, but I intended to have a little bit more consistency, hence the question.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens Using the solution already implemented at jquery will not answer the question.

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes, I have called query(), returning some items and called each for those to perform some actions. Then, I would like to query them to find some descendants and call an each for them.

Comment: @LajosArpad, I know. It was a advice.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens I have been using jquery since 2009. I know it has a solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad So, you are looking for a method to concatenate two nodelist while avoiding duplicates?

Comment: When you recollect a HTML element, compare with strict equal (`===`).

Comment: @gurvinder372 That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Uh, don't you know about [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)? Also keep these methods on the `Element` interface, not on the `Node` interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to concatenate two NodeList objects into one, avoiding duplicates

Use [isSameNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode) and `Array.from`

```
Array.from( nodeList1 ).forEach( function( ele, index ){
  var isDuplicate = Array.from( nodeList2 ).some( ( ele2 ) => ele.isSameNode(ele2) );
  if ( !isDuplicate )
  {  
      nodeList2[ nodeList2.length ] = ele;
  }
})
```

Now `nodeList2` has all the nodes from `nodeList1` which are not duplicates.

**Demo**

```js
var nodeList1 = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".a") );
var nodeList2 = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".b") );

console.log( "original length " + nodeList1.length, nodeList2.length );

nodeList1.forEach(function(ele, index) {
  var isDuplicate = nodeList2.some( ele2 => ele.isSameNode(ele2));
  //console.log( ele, isDuplicate );
  if (!isDuplicate) {
    nodeList2.push( ele );
  }
});

console.log( "Final length " + nodeList1.length , nodeList2.length );
```

```html
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Comment: Very interesting, I have upvoted it, but at first glance this seems to result in an array. If it is impossible to have a NodeList resulting from the concatenation, then I will accept this answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad Nodelist is a static collection. I don't think I can mutate it

Comment: I am trying share a demo on this.

Comment: The creation of a new NodeList srpings to mind as a possible alternative.

Comment: @LajosArpad If you try to invoke `NodeList()` or `new NodeList()`, it throws an error *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor*

Comment: "*why can't I use the `NodeList` constructor to create a `NodeList`?*" -
Because the [DOM specification for the `NodeList` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) does not specify the [WebIDL \[Constructor\] attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#Constructor), so it cannot be created directly in user scripts. Quoted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38441943/82548

Comment: Okay, it seems that what I initially wanted is impossible and the second best after that is your elegant solution. Very nice, thanks.

Comment: @DavidThomas `toNodeList` given in the link you have shared is quite creative :)

Comment: @LajosArpad You can try the toNodeList method in the link shared by DavidThomas